# clarification about the integral test for convergence

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

I am looking at the intergal test for convergence on wikipedia and in the proof they assume that the function is monotonous in an interval [k,$\infty$) and is continuous almost everywhere.
I have seen multiple places that assume that the function has to be positive and decreasing.

I wanted to ask if the weaker assumption of it being monotonous in the interval is enough for the proof, and is there a different proof than the one in wikipedia that uses this assumption.

I am asking that question since it is confusing that I have seen that many places aren't using the same assumptions as in the wikipedia version and because in my calculus text book the proof itself is a bit confusing to me

Thanks in advance

Comment: imho,  Wikipedia is not a fully reliable source when it comes to mathematics.

Comment: so, what is the reliable source that you recommend?

Comment: "Principles of Mathematical Analysis", by W. Rudin, for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [that article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence), it is assumed that $f$ is monotonous decreasing and that the integral $\int_N^\infty f(t)\,\mathrm dt$ converges. Now, suppose that $f(x_0)<0$ for some $x_0\in[N,\infty)$. Then $f(x)\leqslant f(x_0)$ for each $x\geqslant x_0$. So, for each $x\in[N,\infty)$, if $x\geqslant x_0$,$$\int_N^xf(t)\,\mathrm dt=\int_N^{x_0}f(t)\,\mathrm dt+\int_{x_0}^xf(t)\,\mathrm dt\leqslant\int_N^{x_0}f(t)\,\mathrm dt+f(x_0)(x-x_0)$$and, since $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x_0)(x-x_0)=-\infty$, the integral $\int_N^\infty f(t)\,\mathrm dt$ diverges. But we are assuming otherwise. So, we have $f(x_0)\geqslant0$ for each $x_0\in[N,\infty)$, and therefore asserting that $f$ is monotonous decreasing and that the integral $\int_N^\infty f(t)\,\mathrm dt$ converges actualy imples that we always have $f(x_0)\geqslant0$.

Comment: does the series that we sum in the infinite sum has to consist of non negative integers ?
also, given an infinite sum, do I have to prove that the function is monotonous in order to use the integral test ?

Comment: Yes (to both questions).

Comment: Thank you very much!